# the first homology group Rotman

Tags: group-theory, homology-cohomology

I have a problem in the book "An Introduction to homological algebra" by Rotman, on page 537.
Let $G$ be a group and $\mathbb{Z}$ be trivial $G$-module. There is a short exact sequence 
$$0\to \mathcal{G}\to \mathbb{Z}G\to \mathbb{Z}\to 0.$$

Then Rotman states that the connnecting homomorphism $\partial:H_1(G,\mathbb{Z})=Tor_1^{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})\to H_0(G,\mathcal{G})$ is an isomorphism. Since $H_0(G,\mathcal{G})\cong\mathcal{G}/\mathcal{G}^2$, Rotman gives an explicit formula of isomorphism from $H_1(G,\mathbb{Z})$ to $\mathcal{G}/\mathcal{G}^2$ by $cls(z)\mapsto -z+\mathcal{G}^2.$
By using the Bar resolution 
$$\to B_2\to B_1\to B_0\to \mathbb{Z}\to 0$$
and applying $\mathbb{Z}\otimes_G$, we can get $Tor_1^{\mathbb{Z}G}(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z})=ker(1\otimes d_1)/im(1\otimes d_2)$. But in the explicit formula $z\in \mathcal{G}\subseteq \mathbb{Z}G$, clearly, $z$ is not in $ker(1\otimes d_1)\subseteq \mathbb{Z}\otimes_GB_1$. Where is my fault?